# How to export mysql results in XML to OUTFILE?

Tags: mysql

I can do select with joining a few tables and producing the result set in xml just by passing in -X argument along with mysql command.

But I can't get it to produce xml when including "INTO OUTFILE '/var/temp/myfile.xml'" in the select statement.

How can this be done? I can't use a client as the db is on a remote server.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to work around this by saving the query results into a table then doing a select * on the new table using INTO OUTFILE